# handling key value pair

Tags: angularjs, arrays

HTML:

```
<input  type="text" ng-model="user.fname" ng-disabled="!allow.fname"/>  
<input  type="checkbox" ng-model="allow.fname" /> 
<hr/>
<input  type="text" ng-model="user.lname" ng-disabled="!allow.lname"/>  
<input  type="checkbox" ng-model="allow.lname" /> 
<hr/>
<input  type="text" ng-model="user.sname" ng-disabled="!allow.sname"/>  
<input  type="checkbox" ng-model="allow.sname" />
```

JS:

```
 function MyCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.user = {
          fname: 'First name',
          lname: 'Last name',
          sname: 'Surname'
        };

        $scope.allow = {
          fname : true,
          lname : true,
          sname : true,
        };

        $scope.users = [];

        $scope.push = function(){
            var user = {}, 
                allow = $scope.allow;
          Object.keys(allow).forEach(function(key){
            allow[key] ? user[key] = $scope.user[key] : null;
          });
          $scope.users.push(user);
        } 
    }
```

By using above code , I am able to push key and values in array when checkbox is set as true . Same thing I wanted to do when glyphicon close is set as true and glyphicon open set as false. But I am facing issue , that glyphicon is set as true by default and all my keyname by default moving into array , if I set condition as false to make glyphicon open initially, the push is not working.

```
 <script>$('#menu-toggle').click( function(){
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close');
});</script>
```

Html:

```
JS:

     $scope.hiddenFields = function() {


            var data = $scope.dataArray[0];


            var keyArray = ["firstname", "lastname", "dob"];

           if($scope.afname == true) {
                    $scope.hide.push("firstname");
                    console.log($scope.hide); 
                } 
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cbrz2qac/

Comment: In fiddle, where is glyphicon ?

Comment: I did that for checkbox , when I did for glyphicon it shows error. I shared my proper working code.

Comment: can you please add glyphicon in fiddle? so that i can prepare it for you in a way of that

Comment: ok I will do it now and share here.

Comment: ok then please let me know

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cbrz2qac/ please have a look

Answer (score 0):

I have added a working snippet below. There are better ways to use `ng-class`, but I'll leave that to you

```
<input  type="text" ng-model="user.fname" ng-disabled="!allow.fname"/>  
<input  type="checkbox" ng-model="allow.fname" /> 
<label ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open': allow.fname, 'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close': !allow.fname }"></label>
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
     fname: 'First name',
      lname: 'Last name',
      sname: 'Surname'
    };
    
    $scope.allow = {
     fname : true,
      lname : true,
      sname : true,
    };
    
    $scope.users = [];
    
    $scope.push = function(){
     var user = {}, 
        allow = $scope.allow;
      Object.keys(allow).forEach(function(key){
       allow[key] ? user[key] = $scope.user[key] : null;
      });
      $scope.users.push(user);
    } 
}
```

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input  type="text" ng-model="user.fname" ng-disabled="!allow.fname"/>  
  
  <label ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open': !allow.fname, 'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close': allow.fname }"><input  type="checkbox" ng-model="allow.fname" /> </label>
  <hr/>
  <input  type="text" ng-model="user.lname" ng-disabled="!allow.lname"/>  
  <input  type="checkbox" ng-model="allow.lname" /> 
   <label ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open': !allow.lname, 'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close': allow.lname }"> <input  type="checkbox" ng-model="allow.lname" /> </label>
  <hr/>
  <input  type="text" ng-model="user.sname" ng-disabled="!allow.sname"/>  
  
   <label ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open': !allow.sname, 'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close': allow.sname }"><input  type="checkbox" ng-model="allow.sname" /> </label>
  <hr/>
  <button ng-click="push()">Push It</button>
  <br/>
  <label>Results</label>
  <ul ng-repeat="u in users">
    <li>{{u}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi the code you gave exactly run as mine, the thing is when I click glyphicon (glyphicon close) I want to push that particular value into array, whereas here it happens in reverse way,checkout

Comment: Hi , By default I need eye to be open , when eyeicon is clicked only it should push the value into array . The problem is I am  working on hide fields, so by default I can not show eyeicon as closed.

Comment: also see your code, initially by default it comes as eye close and array pushed is empty, but after second time it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

write html like It will work

```
<head>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <input  type="text" ng-model="user.fname" ng-disabled="!allow.fname"/>
  <span ng-show="allow.fname"  class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
  <span ng-show="!allow.fname" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close"></span>
  <input  type="checkbox" ng-model="allow.fname" /> 
  <hr/>
  <input  type="text" ng-model="user.lname" ng-disabled="!allow.lname"/>
  <span ng-show="allow.lname"  class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
  <span ng-show="!allow.lname" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close"></span>
  <input  type="checkbox" ng-model="allow.lname" /> 
  <hr/>
  <input  type="text" ng-model="user.sname" ng-disabled="!allow.sname"/> 
  <span ng-show="allow.sname"  class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
  <span ng-show="!allow.sname" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close"></span>
  <input  type="checkbox" ng-model="allow.sname" /> 
  <hr/>
  <button ng-click="push()">Push It</button>
  <br/>
  <label>Results</label>
  <ul ng-repeat="u in users">
    <li>{{u}}</li>
```

Comment: Hi , on clicking on eye , it doesnt work .check your code.

Comment: check this plunker

Comment: Hi , I need in reverse way , when eye is close want to push the values into array.This is how my code too works. please check my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cbrz2qac/

Comment: above js fiddle open eyed can be push into aray

Comment: this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cbrz2qac/15/ For Closed Eyes push int array

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution here , Have a look anyways thanks for your suggestions ,it really helped me a lot.

html:

```
   <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input  type="text" ng-model="user.fname" ng-disabled="!allow.fname"/>  

  <label ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close': allow.fname, 'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open': !allow.fname }"><input  type="checkbox" ng-model="allow.fname" /> </label>
  <hr/>
  <input  type="text" ng-model="user.lname" ng-disabled="!allow.lname"/>  
  <input  type="checkbox" ng-model="allow.lname" /> 
   <label ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open': !allow.lname, 'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close': allow.lname }"> <input  type="checkbox" ng-model="allow.lname" /> </label>
  <hr/>
  <input  type="text" ng-model="user.sname" ng-disabled="!allow.sname"/>  

   <label ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open': !allow.sname, 'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close': allow.sname }"><input  type="checkbox" ng-model="allow.sname" /> </label>
  <hr/>
  <button ng-click="push()">Push It</button>
  <br/>
  <label>Results</label>
  <ul ng-repeat="u in users">
    <li>{{u}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
        fname: 'First name',
      lname: 'Last name',
      sname: 'Surname'
    };

    $scope.allow = {
        fname : true,
      lname : true,
      sname : true,
    };

    $scope.users = [];

    $scope.push = function(){
        var user = {}, 
            allow = $scope.allow;
      Object.keys(allow).forEach(function(key){
        allow[key] ? user[key] = $scope.user[key] : null;
      });
      $scope.users.push(user);
    } 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cbrz2qac/13/